# Executing Maven3 exec plugin with no inheritance

Tags: java, maven, exec

I have a multi module maven java project where I want to execute the exec plugin in order to execute a custom command after the Jars has been created.

I call **maven package assembly:assembly exec:exec** on the parent POM to create the project output.

I used the following in the parent POM:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <executable>myExecutable.exe</executable>
            <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
            <arguments>....</arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

When doing so, my executable got executed correctly but was executed for every child module as well.

In order to try and fix it, I've set the plugin to not get inherit to the child modules:

```
<inherited>false</inherited>
```

But now the exec plugin fails with a **The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid** error.

I've tried setting the plugin to run under the "executions" element and assign it to a maven life cycle phase. This caused the executable to run successfully, but I am unable to do this since I need to execute other plugins (assembly plugin) before I execute this exec plugin.

How can I run this (exec) plugin just once after the package phase has completed and the other plugin (assembly) has been finished as well?

In other words, I want to execute 'package' for all of my child modules and then execute the exec plugin just once from the parent.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Sounds like a kind of integration test you want to start?

Comment: No. I'm executing a WIX project in order to build an MSI from the output of all my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a command at the parent POM level, you are telling Maven to invoke that part of the lifecycle *for every module*.

If you only want to invoke exec:exec for the child module, you should only declare that plugin for the child module (as it has no meaning for other modules that inherit the parent) and invoke Maven with the `--projects` or `-pl` argument:

mvn -pl child package assembly:assembly exec:exec

This command, when executed from the parent project, executes `package assembly:assembly exec:exec` for only the child project.

However, if what you really are trying to accomplish is that you can `package` all of the modules in a single command, *and* you want the `assembly:assembly` and `exec:exec` goals to be executed for that child module during the `package` phase, then [you want to bind these plugins to that phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins). For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>myExecutable.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
        <arguments>....</arguments>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <!-- run the exec goal of this plugin every time this module is packaged -->
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I think I may have not been clear enough. I want the exec plugin to run at the PARENT module AFTER 'package' phase has been executed for all the child modules. In other words, I want to perform a package for all my child modules and afterwards execute the exec plugin just once. I do not want the plugin to run at any child module.

Comment: You could perhaps bind the assembly and exec plugins to the `integration-test` phase or a similar phase that happens after `package` but before `install`. To have the assembly plugin execute before the exec plugin, either choose a prior stage for assembly than exec or bind them both to the same stage but list the assembly one first (the ordering of listing in pom.xml matters for stuff like that). http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: Can I ask what the program that will be executed will do though? Knowing it's nature might help understand the best way to accomplish what you are looking for, or to figure out if it even fits into the idea of Maven at all. Is it some sort of integration test, or something that checks the validity of your packaged output?

Comment: I can't bind it to a later phase like 'integration-test' since I have some integration tests running at that phase which I don't always want to run. I'm running a WIX project using the 'exec' plugin. The wix project is creating an MSI from the output of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

This will skip inheritance on `exec-maven-plugin` executions previously configured:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>none</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  ...
</build>
```